# in VBA powerpoint How to add a new slide to an empty presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to add a new slide to an empty presentation. I am struggling with the layout.
I am Using the following:

```
Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout)
sld.Design = ActivePresentation.Designs(1)
```

This code works fine when i already have a slide in my presentation, but i don't!

So, my question is: how can i insert a slide if i don't have a preexisting slide to set the layout from it?
I mean in the first line of the code i am defining a layout using slide 1 in order to use it in the .AddSlide

Comment: The code works fine for me. I created a new powerpoint. Deleted the starting slide and then ran the code. It added a new slide.

Comment: So strange, that it works with you!
I am not a VBA expert to tell why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use something like this :

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.Add Index:=ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutCustom
```

With that **you don't have to get the layout from elsewhere** and you can change it, see some of the other possiblities that you have on screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Hi it gives me activeX can't create object error even though I included the reference to Micorsoft Ppt library any idea about this error ?

Comment: @newguy : Can you create a question and paste the link here? Not easy to solve without seeing your code! (And that particular error is quite a pain...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816016/activex-cant-create-object-powerpont-vba/39816402#39816402 This was the question it's solved now.

Comment: Where did you get this table from, please?

Comment: @chikitin : It's called "Object Browser", you can access it on Windows via F2 and I think it doesn't exist on Mac

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the OP's code works for me

```
Dim appPPT As PowerPoint.Application
dim ppObj As PowerPoint.Presentation
dim slideObj As PowerPoint.Slide
dim pptLayout As CustomLayout

Set appPPT = New PowerPoint.Application
Set ppObj = appPPT.Presentations.Add
Set pptLayout = ppObj.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(7)
Set slideObj = ppObj.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout)
```

Comment: Usually 7th CustomLayout is a blank slide. But, not always. So, to create a blank slide more safely, you'd better use "ActivePresentation.Slides.Add ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1,  ppLayoutBank" as R3uK said.