# ActiveX can't create object powerpont vba

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to copy 1st slide from the powerpoint and insert it at the end but I am getting ActiveX can't create object on the line

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
```

This is my full code and I've added the reference to microsoft powerpoint library as well

```
Option Explicit

Dim myFile, Fileselected As String, Path As String, objPPT As Object
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sub Generate_PPTs()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose Template PPT File."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
    Fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Path = Fileselected

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set objPPT = objPPT.Presentations.Open(Path)

Debug.Print objPPT.Name

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste Index:=objPPT.Slides.Count + 1

Set activeSlide = objPPT.Slides(objPPT.Slides.Count)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set objPPT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: are you running this code from PowerPoint or Excel ?

Comment: from Excel that's why I add the reference to the Library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try edited code below, I have `ppApp  As PowerPoint.Application`  and  `Dim ppPres  As PowerPoint.Presentation` :

```
Option Explicit

Dim myFile, Fileselected As String, Path As String, objPPT As Object
Dim ppApp   As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres  As PowerPoint.Presentation

Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sub Generate_PPTs()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose Template PPT File."
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
    Fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Path = Fileselected

Dim i As Integer

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
i = 1

ppApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=Path  ' 'PowerPointFile = "C:\Test.pptx"
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(i)

' for debug
Debug.Print ppPres.Name

ppPres.Slides(1).Copy
ppPres.Slides.Paste Index:=ppPres.Slides.Count + 1

Set activeSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppPres.Slides.Count)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ppPres = Nothing
Set ppApp = Nothing

End Sub
```